# How to connect to Postgres with Kotlin/Ktor with plugin start

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, plugins, configure, ktor

I have decided to start learning Kotlin/Ktor. I have created a project in Intellij and selected the Postgres plugin. I'm reading the instructions of how to set it up from the file it created:

```
/**
* Makes a connection to a Postgres database.
* 
* In order to connect to your running Postgres process,
* please specify the following parameters in your configuration file:
* postgres.url -- Url of your running database process.
* postgres.user -- Username for database connection
* postgres.password -- Password for database connection

 **/
```

But I cant figure out where to set the username or password (or url). It refers to a configuration file but I have no idea where that is.

Here are all my file structure if it helps.

[All files part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFL22.png)

[All files part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V0tU.png)

[All files part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVfPR.png)

I have tried the Navigate - > Search everywhere" option for keywords such as password and postgres but found nothing that looks like where I can configure the password or username.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is supposed to be an `application.conf` file in your resources folder, if it is not there, that means you chose your configurations to be in code when you created the project the first time.

Look at the following image: [Ktor Project creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr2X2.png), in the bottom it asks where to set up your configurations, choose HOCON file instead of Code. By this way, you will have `application.conf` file in your resources folder.
In that file, add the following code snippet to configure Postgres:

```
postgres {
    url = "Your URL"
    user = "Your USERNAME"
    password = "Your PASSWORD"
}
```

However, for security purposes, you should not write your database credentials as plaintext in your configuration file. For your production, consider using environment variables and configure Postgres like this:

```
postgres {
    url = ${pg_url}
    user = ${pg_username}
    password = ${pg_password}
}
```

where `pg_url`, `pg_username`, and `pg_password` are the defined environment variables in your system.

Finally, to access the url, user, and password in your code, Do it like this:

```
val url = environment.config.property("postgres.url").getString()
val user = environment.config.property("postgres.user").getString()
val password = environment.config.property("postgres.password").getString()
```

For more info about configuring your project in the file, refer to the [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/configuration-file.html#configuration-file-overview). Hope my answer helps.

Comment: This solved it and explained why i did not find  the file. Thanks

Comment: You are wlecome

Comment: So, if I want my configurations to be in code I should simply paste them raw instead of retrieving them from the environment.config?